# creates a line break before and after drop down menu in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

When I created a drop down menu using css, it generates a line break before and after drop down menu
Here is html code

```
<body>
<!--nav class="navi"-->
<div class="navi" id="navi">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Company Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Core Values And Mission</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Strategy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Brands</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HAMARA GLUCOSE D</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">HAMARA HEALTH CARE PATENT PRODUCTS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">WAHT'S NEW</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Nutrition Space</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Product FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Health & Wellness</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Media</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">News Paper Clippings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Product Photos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Founder which...</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">HSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Copackers & Investors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Communities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<!--/nav-->
</body>
```

and here is css code

```
<style>
.navi ul li
{
    float:left;
}
.navi ul li a
{
    display:block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navi ul li:hover > a
{
    color:white;
}
.navi ul
{
    display:inline-table;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0 0px;
    position:relative;
    background:#C93;

}
.navi ul ul
{
    display: none;  
    position:absolute;
}
.navi ul ul li
{
    /*display:block;*/
    float:none;
}
.navi ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;  
    background:#FC0707;
}
</style>
```

So I don't want to generate a line break

Comment: What have you already attempted to resolve this problem? Are you taking flying lessons?

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AR5xz/
What is the problem? I don't see any... What browser are you developping on?

Comment: I got it now....temp fix could be setting up the line-height

Comment: `line break` = white space = `margin` or sometimes it's `padding` in CSS jargon :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   *{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;   
    }
```

Add this to styles

Comment: Good practice but not solution here.

Comment: I thing this is exactly the problem, if "line break" from OP = top and bottom margin..

Comment: using [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) would be even better practice

Comment: @deathApril, had misunderstood the question. This is the solution. +1!

Answer (score 0):

If you meant the first layer of `a` remove `display:block;` from below code else if it is the second layer of `a` i.e. menu options

Try chaning

> .navi ul li a {
>       display:block;
>       padding: 10px;
>       text-decoration:none; }

to

> .navi ul li > a {
>       display:block;
>       padding: 10px;
>       text-decoration:none; }

I believe that `block` style has been applied to ALL the `a`  creating a break inside the menu options too

Answer (score 0):

try using the white-space property

assign this to the div:

```
.navi
{
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[some more examples](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/)

Comment: still giviing line space

Answer (score 0):

Where it generates line break? By default div display type is block which takes 100% width of its parent and obviously pushed content down which is next to it in the flow.
Do you want to add content before and after the menu?

```
#navi{
  display: inline;
}
```

Also make before and after content's display property to inline ( if no width is specified ) or inline-block ( if you want to specify width ).